# Create a Global Shortcut for a Single Letter

Tags: macos, keybindings

The "w" key on my MacBook Pro broke due to water damage. Currently I am copy and pasting the letter whenever I need that, but I would prefer to be able to press a keyboard shortcut to type it.

The shortcut needs to be available no matter the app; I would prefer the shortcut to be control + option (just those two keys) but if that's not possible then I'll settle for something else.

I tried setting a shortcut through the settings app, but I couldn't figure out how to 1) bind a single letter and 2) have the shortcut available globally.

I'm running Yosemite 10.10.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BetterTouchTool is another great example.

Download BTT from [here](http://bettertouchtool.net). Once you have it open go to the keyboard option and enter in your shortcut (I chose <kbd>opt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> since that should be an uncommon shortcut). After that you then set your 'trigger predefined action' to 'paste custom text' and paste in your 'w'.

Whenever you need to write a 'w' you can now press <kbd>opt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>.

Answer (score 5):

One relatively simple method is to assign a text input that is then converted into "w" when you type your sequence.

I have chosen to type "(v)" that is converted to "w", but you can choose what suits you best (and what you can remember).

Open Keyboard-Text pref in the System Preferences, as described in [this Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25635).

Click on the + sign to add a new item.

Now first type your choice, then paste a "w" in the right column.

[image: v vs w]

It will work on almost all OS X apps, but won't work on web pages like this one.

Comment: How do I trigger the conversion? I bound "w" to "*)", but nothing happens.

Comment: I do not know for the "*)" let me try, otherwise it works right away. It works as well.

Comment: It seems to only work in built-in mac apps (text-edit, mail, etc.) Not what I'm looking for.

Comment: That is what I said in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. I did ask for a global solution.

Comment: Which key on your keyboard are you ready to sacrifice to remap it in to "w"

Comment: As mentioned in my post, alt + option . Alternatively, alt + z is convenient.

Comment: OK, try the karabiner app it might suits you. https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26322/discussion-between-peragon-and-buscarsd).

Answer (score 1):

Buscar's answer gives you a good option.

Another way that you can do this is to show the <kbd>Keyboard Viewer</kbd> which you can access from the menu bar. It will show up as a flag if you set it to display that way next to the volume icon.

[image]

Then all you need to do is mouse click the <kbd>W</kbd> when you need to use it.

**UPDATE**

A universal keyboard option would be to use a clipboard manager. If you read [this article](http://www.macworld.com/article/2887279/clipboard-managers-for-mac.html) it will tell you more about them. From the article it says that they all have a way of favoriting a particular past and assigning it to a key combination like <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>, etc.

**UPDATE 2**

bjbk gave me an idea. You could get one of the wireless blue-tooth keyboards that Apple ships with iMacs. Then you just connect via blue-tooth and brand new keyboard, and it slips in the same pocket as a laptop. I have seen many people pair these with iPads.

Comment: I'd prefer a keyboard solution - I find suddenly switching to the trackpad inconvenient.

Comment: Unfortunately most apps will have their own keybinding settings. They usually avoid the system bindings, or use the same ones, which is why some "global" commands like `cmd` + `C` work as Copy for all apps. This is the one way that will insure global support, but I understand your preference.

Comment: Another albeit clunky option would be to carry around an external keyboard either wired or wireless. Just saying for the sake of mentioning.

Comment: @bjbk I have one on my desk because I could never find a better option for a numeric keypad. Couldn't you also connect with the blue-tooth keyboard that comes with iMacs?

Comment: @AMR one sure can no problem.

Comment: Using an external keyboard is not an option - I very rarely have a good place to put it, and I'd rather not buy a keyboard + bag.